# Best way to build kick start lever for motorcycle

Tags: forging

Let's say I want to build a new kick start lever for my bike, what's the best way to make one? Is it (Hot/Cold) Forging or Casting? I'm looking for the materials too, do you think chro-moly steel a good choice? Thanks! [image: Kick start lever]

Answer (score 1):

That likely made in two or even three pieces.

From the right the clamp will be designed to have some flex as it is clamped to the splines on the starting shaft.

The bent rod or shaft will be made of a less flexible material as it has to support the force applied as you kickstart. The joint may be the same material so the foot peg can fold out of the way.

An old spanner could be re-modelled into the bent rod as spanners don't flex much, but they are also shaped so the width takes the applied load.

Comment: If you insist on making one yourself , a 1/2 drive breaker bar would be a good place to start . As @solar mike says it will be hardened low alloy steel and one end may be a shape you can used with little machining.

Answer (score 1):

Buy one. The one shown is a forging, that is how the end shapes are formed. Low alloy steel to be quench and tempered after forging and machining , not something to do in a garage. Chrome/ moly like 41XX is cost effective , but chrome/  moly/ nickel like 86XX is also good ( and common). Someone would need to determine the load; then calculate the diameter and the necessary hardness ( strength) to be developed by the Q & T.